# Why is the bar button item only visible when selected and very dull?

Tags: xcode, swift

[image]I have added a bar button item in my app and it is only visible on the storyboard when it is selected , it is not visible at all when I run it on the simulator or real device, any ideas of how I could solve this? thanks !

Comment: Do you have any screenshots?

Comment: Just added one @ILikeTau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are already in a UINavigationController interface. Thus, adding your own navigation bar to this view controller won't work; it is hidden behind the navigation controller's navigation bar. What you want to do is modify the *navigation controller's* navigation bar. You do that by adding a *navigation item* to this view controller, not a navigation bar.